# Invoking a variable from within a Windows Batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

Folks,

I'm trying to set a variable using a for loop and executing a command based on the set variable. But when I do try to do that I get odd behaviour.

The command:

```
FOR /D %%G in (*) DO SET matr=%%~nG&& robocopy %matr%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook "E:\Backup - %computername%\Users\%matr%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook" /s /b /log+:"E:\Backup - %computername%\Log de Backup.txt" /v /A-:SHR /r:2 /w:5 /tee
```

Explanation:

For every folder in a given folder (C:\Users\, stated earlier on my script), set a variable called matr with the name of the folder. The aim is to, at every loop, look for the next folder inside C:\Users and set the variable as the name of the folder.
After that, I run robocopy using the variable as starting point for the source. For exemple, the first folder found on C:\Users would be administrator, and that should make my robocop use administrator\Appdata\Local\Microsoft\Outlook as source.
The destination would use the variable too to target a folder in an external drive, in an specific folder in it.

This is the behaviour I get when I run the script with administrative privileges:

```
E:\>cd /D C:\Users\ 

C:\Users>FOR / %G in (*) DO SET matr=%~nG  && robocopy \AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook "E:\Backup - P43971\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook" /s /b /log+:"E:\Backup - P43971\Log de Backup.txt" /v /A-:SHR /r:2 /w:5 /tee 

C:\Users>SET matr=Administrador  && robocopy \AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook "E:\Backup - P43971\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook" /s /b /log+:"E:\Backup - P43971\Log de Backup.txt" /v /A-:SHR /r:2 /w:5 /tee
```

I don't understand why the variable gets blanked out.
I tried putting SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION and using !matr! instead of %matr% but to no avail. When using !matr! instead of %matr% the batch recognizes it as direct text and not a variable call.

Relevant parts of the code:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

cd /D C:\Users\

FOR /D %%G in (*) DO SET matr=%%~nG&& robocopy %matr%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook "E:\Backup - %computername%\Users\%matr%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook" /s /b /log+:"E:\Backup - %computername%\Log de Backup.txt" /v /A-:SHR /r:2 /w:5 /tee

echo Outlook backup done!
echo.

pause
```

Behavior when NOT setting enabledelayedexpansion AND using single %matr%:

```
E:\>cd /D C:\Users\ 

C:\Users>FOR / %G in (*) DO SET matr=%~nG  && robocopy \AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook "E:\Backup - P43971\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook" /s /b /log+:"E:\Backup - P43971\Log de Backup.txt" /v /A-:SHR /r:2 /w:5 /tee 

C:\Users>SET matr=Administrador  && robocopy \AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook "E:\Backup - P43971\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook" /s /b /log+:"E:\Backup - P43971\Log de Backup.txt" /v /A-:SHR /r:2 /w:5 /tee
```

Behaviour when setting enabledelayedexpansion and using double %%matr%%:

```
E:\>cd /D C:\Users\ 

C:\Users>FOR / %G in (*) DO SET matr=%~nG  && robocopy %matr%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook "E:\Backup - P43971\Users\%matr%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook" /s /b /log+:"E:\Backup - P43971\Log de Backup.txt" /v /A-:SHR /r:2 /w:5 /tee 

C:\Users>SET matr=Administrador  && robocopy %matr%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook "E:\Backup - P43971\Users\%matr%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook" /s /b /log+:"E:\Backup - P43971\Log de Backup.txt" /v /A-:SHR /r:2 /w:5 /tee
```

Behaviour when set enabledelayedexpansion and using single !matr!:

```
E:\>cd /D C:\Users\ 

C:\Users>FOR / %G in (*) DO SET matr=%~nG  && robocopy !matr!\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook "E:\Backup - P43971\Users\!matr!\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook" /s /b /log+:"E:\Backup - P43971\Log de Backup.txt" /v /A-:SHR /r:2 /w:5 /tee 

C:\Users>SET matr=Administrador  && robocopy !matr!\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook "E:\Backup - P43971\Users\!matr!\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook" /s /b /log+:"E:\Backup - P43971\Log de Backup.txt" /v /A-:SHR /r:2 /w:5 /tee
```

Comment: On closer inspection, please notice that in each of the 3 run-reports (were they retyped, or patched by cut-and-paste?) the `for` line reads `for / %G` - the `D` is missing. Are you using a proper text-editor like Editplus or Notepad++? If you are, ensure you are saving the file as ANSI, not Unicode. If you are trying to use Notepad or a word-processor, then try using a proper text-editor as these utilities may try to format the file to make "sense".

Answer (score 1):

You need to read some SO articles on `delayed expansion` carefully, and **show us** how you `tried putting SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION and using !matr! instead of %matr%` as we can't see your terminal very clearly from here.

The quick answer is to not use `matr` at all. Try

```
FOR /D %%G in (*) DO robocopy %%~nG\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook "E:\Backup - %computername%\Users\%%~nG\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook" /s /b /log+:"E:\Backup - %computername%\Log de Backup.txt" /v /A-:SHR /r:2 /w:5 /tee
```

where `%%~nG` will probably contain what you expect.

Comment: Tried to use that and it appears that robocop is not so robust after all. I get a error message stating either that %~nG wasn't expected OR that it can't be used at that moment. Although when I run the command outside a batch script it works fine.
I will edit my post with the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: @aphoria: No - `%%G` throughout *or* `%G` throughout - depending on whether the command is being executed as a *batch line* or *diectly from the prompt*.

Comment: @OP: Are you attempting to run this from within a batch file, or from the prompt? If within a batch file, then It should work as I wrote it. If from the prompt, all `%%G`/`%%~nG` should be `%G`/`%~nG`. If you are attempting to execute from the prompt, then `!var!` will not work since `delayedexpansion` is only in effect in the local environment established by `setlocal`. In that case, you *may* use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion&...set var=%G&robocopy..!var!...`

Comment: I don't have the slightest clue why, but if I put a blank line between `cd /D C:\Users\` and `FOR /D %%G in (*) DO robocopy %%~nG\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook "E:\Backup - %computername%\Users\%%~nG\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook" /s /b /log+:"E:\Backup - %computername%\Log de Backup.txt" /v /A-:SHR /r:2 /w:5 /tee` the batch fails. If I delete the empty line in between, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```bat
FOR /D %%G in (*) DO
```

You could use this:

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B/AD') Do
```

Alternatively this suggestion instead uses a different way of parsing the user profile names. It uses `WMIC` to retrieve all local non-special profile names in a `For /F` loop:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "SP=AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook"
Set "DP=E:\Backup - %ComputerName%"
Set "BL=Log de Backup.txt"
Set "RP=/S /B /A-:RSH /R:2 /W:5 /V /TEE"

For /F Tokens^=2^Delims^=^" %%A In ('WMIC Path Win32_UserProfile Where^
 "Special!='TRUE'" Assoc /AssocClass:Win32_UserAccount 2^>Nul'
) Do For /F "Tokens=1*Delims==" %%B In ('WMIC UserAccount Where^
 "SID='%%A' And LocalAccount='TRUE'" Get Name /Value'
) Do For /F "Tokens=*" %%D In ("%%C"
) Do RoboCopy "%%D\%SP%" "%DP%\Users\%%D\%SP%" %RP% /LOG+:"%DP%\%BL%"
```

*`All Users`, `Default`, `Default User` and `Public` are examples of special system service profiles which would be ignored using this method but not using the `Dir` example*

Comment: Holy crap, I can't understand half of this. I will try and read about it and report back, thanks!

Comment: @RafaelUmbelino, I have fixed some bad typos.

Comment: For /F gets me a blank/empty variable when I try to print the variable, the second snipet simply gets ignored in the batch with an error message of something similar to "Description = invalid consult".

Comment: Just to make sure you've copied the exact syntax correctly, what is the output when you enter the following single line, _unchanged_, at your command prompt; `For /F Tokens^=2^Delims^=^" %A In ('WMIC Path Win32_UserProfile Where "Special!='TRUE'" Assoc /AssocClass:Win32_UserAccount 2^>Nul') Do @For /F "Tokens=1*Delims==" %B In ('WMIC UserAccount Where "SID='%A' And LocalAccount='TRUE'" Get Name /Value') Do @For /F "Tokens=*" %D In ("%C") Do @Echo [%D]`